# Stack list elements to make an array?

Tags: python, numpy

I have a list of arrays X with len(X) = 53 i.e np arrays. Each of those arrays has n lines and 303 cols/elements. To give a more down to earth intuition: I have 53 images and from each I extract n (different) parts each represented by 303 long feature vectors.

How can I put everything together to have X as an array with `X.shape=(53*n_parts, 303)`

For training I need to have X (feature vectors) and the target Y, but in this case, each training example's X is a 303 element vector. So I must find a way to produce an array with 53* n_parts elements of 303 feature vectors.

Comment: Are you talking about numpy? You shall describe context of your questions.

Comment: please share some input and expected output of code so that we can understand easily and read stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are [several functions](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/routines.array-manipulation.html#joining-arrays) for stacking arrays together in numpy. It seems that in your case the most useful is [`np.vstack`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.vstack.html#numpy.vstack):

```
import numpy as np
result_array = np.vstack(tuple(list_of_arrays))
```

Mind that `vstack` takes a tuple of arrays, so you might need a type conversion.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you are trying to do. But you might want to do like this?

```
n_parts = 10
img1  = np.empty(shape=(n_parts, 303), dtype=int)
img2  = np.empty(shape=(n_parts, 303), dtype=int)
...
img53 = np.empty(shape=(n_parts, 303), dtype=int)

imgs = np.empty(shape=(53, n_parts, 303), dtype=int)

imgs[0] = img1
imgs[1] = img2
...
imgs[52] = img53
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're doing some sort of Principal Component Analysis.

You'll want to test the performance of these methods yourself.

Lets first talk about your data, you have a 53-by-*n*-by-303 3-dimensional matrix.  I'm assuming the value of *n* is consistent across all images.

### Method 1

You likely want to vectorize your image data, so for each image, instead of it being *n*-by-303, you'll make it 1-by-(*n* * 303) -- in other words, the first element of the row vector will be the first element of the first row, the 304th element of the row vector will be the first element of the second row, etc.

So for each image you'll have a row vector, and for the entire set of 53 images, you'll have 53 row vectors.  Together these can form a matrix -- which will end up being 53-by-(# of pixels) matrix.

```
# Convert the elements of X to row vectors
for i,x in enumerate(X): X[i] = x.reshape(1, size(x))

# Convert the row vectors to a matrix
XX = np.vstack(X)
```

From there, you can slice the components you're interested in:

```
components = [1,517,1267,...]

FV = XX[:,components]
```

At this point, `FV` is a 53-by-(# components) matrix.

### Method 2

Instead of creating the huge matrix and slicing it down, instead you'd only extract the components you were interested in from each array.

```
components = [1,517,1267,...]

FV = np.empty([53, size(components)])

for i,x in enumerate(X):
    row = x.reshape(1, size(x))  # Row is the image matrix, reshaped as a row vector
    FV[i] = row[:, components]
```

or

```
components = [1,517,1267,...]

for i,x in enumerate(X):
    # Don't explicitly flatten the matrix, just use the 1-D iterator
    FV[i] = row.flat[components]
```

At this point, `FV` is a 53-by-(# components) matrix.